# docker-compose up stuck on attaching to

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to dockerize my react app.

Whenever i run `docker-compose up` it gets stuck on "Attaching to"

**Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 0 - Pre-requisite: Based On Node.js to BUILD and compile App.

FROM node:10.15.0-alpine as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install 

COPY ./ /app/

RUN npm run build

# Stage 1 - Based On Nginx to have ONLY a compiled and PRODUCTION ready build.

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

COPY --from=node /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  idcheck-demo:
    image: idcheck-demo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**nginx-custom.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Ive tried attempting to access it by going to 0.0.0.0:8080 but it just returns me with the following error in the browser

> This page isn’t working 0.0.0.0 didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Have you tried running `docker-compose logs idcheck-demo` to find out whether any errors have been logged?

Comment: @Hongli it just returns "Attaching to idcheck-demo_idcheck-demo_1"

Comment: I have the same issue with my stack...

Answer (score 4):

In my case was a port forwarding at the `docker-compose.yml`. I was doing the forward to 8080 when the exposed port was the 80 so when I've changed the port forwarding to 80 at the `docker-compose.yml` the service have done as should be.

Answer (score 2):

First check if the container is up. You can do this by running:

```
docker-compose ps
```

In case of your configuration I got:

```
         Name                   Command          State               Ports             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54368216_idcheck-demo_1   nginx -g daemon off;   Up      80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

as you can see container is running with nginx not being daemonized which explains why the console is hanging after you run docker-compose up.

You can also run a quick telnet to see if the HTTP service is responding correctly:

```
telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Bottom line is that console stuck on "Attaching to..." is caused by the nginx process not running as a daemon.

You can put the container into background running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: `docker-compose up -d` will put the container into background

Comment: This did not solve my problem, i solved it by adding configuration in my nginx to turn of daemon

Comment: doesn't this cause your container to stop?

Comment: It is does not solve the issue. I cannot see logs container  and It is not yet fully up and not accessible server in browser even it is showing running.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I start nginx using "docker-compose up". And the reason is Port Conflict, so I fix it by changing Ports Configuration.

Comment: This also happened to me and what I did was expose the port of nginx and used `docker compose up -d`